# Django - How to make a model that when an instance of this model is created, that data is saved to a page that is unique to a user

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, django-models

I'm making a website where you can post jobs to an 'explore page', and I was then wondering how I would go about making it so that when a job is posted to that 'explore page', that job will also be posted to a page where the person who posted the job can manage all of the jobs they have posted i.e. edit, delete. I can post jobs to the explore page but I need to find a way for the job to save to the 'employers' page

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from base.forms import JobForm

@login_required(login_url='login')
def manage_jobs(request):
    if request.user.is_employee:
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = JobForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        context = {"form":form}
        return render(request, 'employer/manage-jobs.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.manage_jobs, name='manage-jobs'),
]
```

models.py

```
class Job(models.Model):
    company = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, verbose_name="Company/Employer")
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    area_of_filming = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Area Of Filming", default="")
    contact_email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='Contact Email', max_length=60, default='')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)   

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company


class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email', max_length=60, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45, unique=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_employee = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Are you using FilmLink as an employee?')

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name', 'is_employee']

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    class Meta:
        permissions = [
            ("post_jobs", "Can post jobs"),
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_perms(self, perm):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin
```

manage-jobs.html

```
<body>
<button id="myBtn">Post A Job</button>
    <div id="main"></div>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times</span>
        <form action="" method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <div id="company-container">
            <p>Employer Name</p>
            <p id="employer">{{form.company}}</p>
          </div>
          <div id="role-container">
            <p>Role (e.g. Actor, Director)</p>
            <p id="role">{{form.role}}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="area-of-filming-container">
            <p>Area Of Production/Filming</p>
            <p id="area-of-filming">{{form.area_of_filming}}</p>
          </div>
          <div id="contact-email-container">
            <p>Contact Email</p>
            <p id="contact-email">{{form.contact_email}}</p>
          </div>
          <div id="description-container">
            <p>Description Of Job</p>
            <p id="description">{{form.description}}</p>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" id="post-job">Publish Job</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script
      src="{% static 'lng/js/manage-jobs.js' %} "
      type="text/javascript"
    ></script>
  </body>
```

manage-jobs.js

```
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

I hope I've given you enough information + code to answer my question. Sorry about the confusing wording of the title too, I struggled to put that sentence together.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `ListView` from [django.views.generic.list.ListView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#django.views.generic.list.ListView)

You may override `get_queryset` to get desired behaviour:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super().get_queryset()
    qs = qs.filter(user=self.request.user)
    return qs
```

Comment: ListView seems like it might be a viable option, but I'm still wondering how I'd find a way to loop through the jobs posted *per user*. What I can see is that ListView is able to loop through *all* of the jobs, not the jobs posted by each individual user (I'm new enough to django so I don't know too much)

Comment: Override the `get_queryset` method to ass a filter for user-specific posts. Check the updated answer.

Comment: I think this is my last question, but where would I locate that get_queryset function. Would it be in models.py or admin.py or something else?

Comment: Can use this in [class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/).